# Does the assignment operator make a shallow copy of an NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, copy, nsarray

Say I have two arrays:

```
NSArray *A = @[@"Red", @"Blue", @"Yellow"];
NSArray *B = A;
```

Is B technically a shallow copy of A? If I make changes to the data contained in A, B sees those same changes, and vice-versa. When looking at copying in Apple's documentation, simple equality via the "=" operator is not mentioned as a valid way to make a shallow copy. If this doesn't constitute a shallow copy, then what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment (in Objective-C) is not a copy at all.  That is, it's not a copy of the object, it's only a copy of the reference to the object.  There's a reason every object (reference) has to be declared as a pointer.  (Blocks are a special case.)

A shallow copy is done via the copy method, as in: `NSArray *B = [A copy];`

As it happens you can't modify NSArrays, but the principle holds for NSMutableArrays as well.

```
NSMutableArray *a = [@[@"Red", @"Blue", @"Yellow"] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *b = a;
NSMutableArray *c = [a mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@", a[0], b[0], c[0]);  // Prints: Red, Red, Red

b[0] = @"Green";

NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@", a[0], b[0], c[0]);  // Prints: Green, Green, Red

c[0] = @"Purple";

NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@", a[0], b[0], c[0]);  // Prints: Green, Green, Purple
```

Comment: quick question, if assignment is a copy of a reference, as you said, isn't that the same thing as a shallow copy?

Comment: In the second case, wher both a[0] and b[0] change to @"Green", isn't that because b is a shallow copy of a? You made that happen by using an assignment operator, which is the basis of my confusion between a shallow copy vs assignment. They both copy references to an object in memory.

Comment: A shallow copy of an array copies each reference (pointer) contained in the array.  A deep copy would actually make a copy of each of those objects.  Think of a PO box.  You give a key to your friend, and now he or you can access the same PO box.  That's a reference copy/assignment.  If, instead, he gets his own PO box, photocopies all the letters in yours and puts the copies into his, he's made a shallow copy.

Comment: so then a deep copy, in that context, would be an exact duplicate of the PO box AND all of the letters in it. Great example, very helpful.

Comment: Sometimes the object you are copying points to other objects.  If you make a copy such that you only copy the pointers to those other objects, you've made a shallow copy.  If you copy the objects being pointed to, and make your copy point to the new copies of those other objects, you've made a deep copy.  Deep copies often have to be recursive to be complete.